# Windows & Mac GUI that discovers local IPs

Tags: windows, macos, user-interface, networking

I need to write an app with a GUI interface that works on Windows and Mac that can be downloaded and installed by the user. My first thought is to do it in Java, but my experience with Java GUIs in school was not easy. The requirements also include that the app will discover its own ip address and all ip addresses on the network.

I have three questions:

1. What is a practical and easy way to make a GUI interface for windows and Mac.
2. How to run ipconfig to get the  IP on the local machine from your recomended programming language.
3. How to 'discover' all IPs on the local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you can use Java Swing. I suggest using Eclipse.

2)

```
    try {
        InetAddress a = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println(a.getHostAddress());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    }
```

it will print the IP address i.e. 169.254.10.19

3) you should perform a sort of ping scan on your network. try to open a connection on port 7 for each ip address, if it returns false, you can skip the IP, otherwise you found one.

Comment: Thanks for this. Eventually I will need to print out IP adresses in a user-friendly format. I understand that ip addresses are in base_2,  so   I don't think I can cast to int ((int)).  I am thinking of the byte array as four 8-bit bytes. How can  I convert each one of the bytes to base ten and make 'pretty' output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If .NET doesn't scare you, consider C# and Mono http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits